# Strong Feller property and uniform continuity ( interpreting Stroock Varadhan 1969 )

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

In the article Diffusion processes with continuous coefficients II (Stroock Varadhan - 1969), the authors begin a section named **Strong Feller property**
with the following:

"Let $P(s, x, t , dy) $ be the transition probabilities of the Markov process corresponding to the coefficients $a_{ij}(s, x)$ and $b_j(s,x)$ . We wish to show that, for $s < t$ and arbitrary $x$, $P(s, x, t , dy)$ is continuous in $s, x$ in the uniform sense. This amounts to showing that for bounded functions $\phi(y)$  the functions
$$U(s,x) = \int \phi(y) P(s,x,t_0, dy)$$
are continuous in $s$ and $x$ for $s < t_0$ , and are equicontinuous provided $\phi$ stays uniformly bounded. Because of the continuity of paths, it suffices to investigate the continuity of $U$ in $x$ for each fixed $s < t_0$ . All continuity properties will depend only on the bound of $\phi$, provided s stays away from $t_0$ "

1) Since $P(s,x, t,dy)$ is a family of probability measures, What does uniform continuity means?

I guess that $\forall \epsilon>0 \, \exists \delta >0$ such that $$d((s,x), (s', x')) < \delta  \;\; s,s'< t\Rightarrow \bar{d}(P(s,x, t,dy),P(s',x', t',dy))< \epsilon $$ where $\bar{d}(\mu,\nu) = \sum_{k} \min\{|\mu(f_k) - \nu(f_k)|\wedge 1\}2^{-k}$($\{f_k\}_k$ is a dense family of funtions on $C(\mathbb{R})$)

2) If convergence is related to convergence of measures, then how does it implies convergence for $\phi$ not necessarily continuous? (I understand that if $\mu_n(f) \to \mu(f)$ for all $f$ bounded implies $\mu_n(f) \to \mu(f)$ for all $f$ continuous and bounded. But it seems that the authors reason in the opposite direction, am I missing something here?)

3 ) why do we need to see equicontinuity  of $U(s,x)$ when $\phi$ stays uniformly bounded

4 ) The continuity of paths implies uniform continuity in $s$? (Isn't continuity of $\phi$ needed in this step?)